# Python 2.7.12- How to have the same length for a new string as well as letters?

Tags: python, string

I've just started learning Python 2.7.12 and in my first homework I was given a string called str2, and I'm supposed to create another string which will be the same length as the previous one. In addition,I need to check the third letter (if it's an Upper I need to convert to lower and the opposite, as well as if it's not a letter, I need to change it with '%').
The other characters of the first string should be copied to the second one.

We were given just the basic commends and nothing else so I can't really solve it. please help me! :)

Comment: Have you done any searching? Checking the length of a string and getting a character at a certain position are extremely basic, and nearly any tutorial on strings would cover this. What's your specific question?

Comment: I know how to check the length of the string I don't know how to create a new one with the same length.

Comment: And about the letter, I know how to check if it's upper or lower but I don't know how to do the condition that if it's none of them it will bring me back '%'.

Comment: Do you know how to use for-loops?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean for loops.. we had only one class in which we were taught the basic commends and if sentence. that's it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a copy of the word but you need to change the 3rd character. That's a problem because strings are immutable in python so you can't just change that character. The trick is to copy the string to something that you can change.

```
tmp = list(str2)
```

Then, you need to figure out how to get information about that character to check it. Turns out there are several useful methods on string objects:

```
>>> dir('some string')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__',
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
'__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', 
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 
'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 
'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 
'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 
'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 
'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 
'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 
'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

So use them to update the value

```
>>> if tmp[2].isupper():
...     tmp[2] = tmp[2].lower()
... elif tmp[2].islower():
...     tmp[2] = tmp[2].upper()
... elif tmp[2].isdigit():
...     tmp[2] = '%'
...
```

And you could make that more compact with

```
>>> tmp[2] = (tmp[2].lower() if tmp[2].isupper()
    else tmp[2].upper() if tmp[2].islower()
    else '%' if tmp[2].isdigit else tmp[2])
```

Finally, put it all back together

```
>>> str3 = ''.join(tmp)
```